# Will NetworkInfo expire on network connection changes?

Tags: android

I have some code like this:

```
public class NetworkHelper {
    private static NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo;

    public NetworkHelper(Context context) {
        mNetworkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    private boolean isConnectedWifi(){
        return (mNetworkInfo != null && mNetworkInfo.isConnected() && mNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the connection type of the device changes, for instance, switching from a WiFi network to mobile, will the static reference mNetworkInfo still work? Should I run getActiveNetworkInfo() again to get a "Valid" value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question here is whether `getActiveNetworkInfo` return a *new* `NetworkInfo` object each call, or it keeps only a single object whose reference is returned each time it's called. If it returns the same object each time, your code works fine.

However, I think it's likely that a new object is returned each call, so you should keep a reference to the `ConnectivityManager` object and call `getActiveNetworkInfo` again each time. It won't have a huge impact on performane, and it's better to go on the safe side.

Comment: I don't know whether you're right, but finally I did the same as what you suggest.

Comment: If it still concerns you, you can compare the references of 2 different `NetworkInfo` objects returned by `getActiveNetworkInfo` to be sure.